# show autocomplete select based on id that I type

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, autocomplete, keyup

I have 2 fields,

The second field is autocomplete select,

I want to filter in second field based on what I typing in first field.

example

1. Agent type I filled : T
2. So in agent number, will show all list with code 'T',

This what I tried so far, the problem is autocomplete not working, but I can show all agent number based on agent type code.

I used 'T' as an id to my api, to filter second field, something like this

source:"/api/agent/"+agent_type,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".fn" ).keyup(function() {

var agent_type = $('#agent_type').val();

    $(function()
    {
         $( "#agent_no" ).autocomplete({

          source:"<?php  print url('/'); ?>/api/agent/"+agent_type,
          minLength: 0,
          select: function(event, ui) {
             $('#agent_no').val(ui.item.value);
             $('#agent_name').val(ui.item.desc);
          },
           change: function( event, ui ) {
             if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) {
                $("#agent_no").val("");
                if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
            } else {
                $("#agent_no").attr("readonly", false);
            }
        }
        }); 
    });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 agent type <input type="text" name="agent_type" id="agent_type" class="form-control fn"  required="" value="" >
 <br>
 agent no <input type="text" name="agent_no" id="agent_no" class="form-control fn"  required="" value="" >
```